# how to format html file, to make it user readable form through code

Tags: html, css, asp.net, format

I have one html file in an asp.net project (you can say it is saved as minified, no extra spaces etc). Full html content is saved as one line.

Is there a way to read the file and format the html and save it back using code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check HtmlTextWriter or XhtmlTextWriter, usage: Formatting Html Output with HtmlTextWriter, maybe HTML construction via HtmlTextWriter will be better?

Also check : LINQ & Lambda, Part 3: Html Agility Pack to LINQ to XML Converter

http://www.manoli.net/csharpformat/, here source code in case you miss it.

Comment: i think the last solution is better. i got the source code of that tool. i think we can use the similar logic to format the html on demand. thanks for the link.

Answer (score 0):

There are may online tools available like

1. http://unminify.com/
2. http://www.textfixer.com/html/uncompress-html-code.php

But if you are using Visual Studio you can use <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>k</kbd><kbd>d</kbd>

Comment: thanks for quick reply, do you mean i can pass the html content to these above mentioned tools and get the formatted content back?, if yes, can you guide me how? in the second link which you provided , i think it just adds a line break after end tags, it does not add proper indenting. i wanted one solution where it will properly format the html including the indent etc.

Comment: i wanted to format the code on demand through code. manually we can do Ctrl+k+d.. but i wanted this to happen through code..